# Is the wilcoxon signed-rank test suitable for zero-inflated data?

Tags: count-data, paired-data, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I have data that look like this:

[image: Data]

(There's 285 entries)

These are paired data, in that each line represents a single seal group that has been counted for entanglements using two different methods of counting (binoculars, and counting in photographs)

I am wanting to compare these to assess whether one method identifies statistically significant more entanglements than the other. I know that photos do identify 17 more than binos, but what test would be appropriate to assess whether this is deemed 'significant'? Obviously this is count data, and so is zero-inflated. I have previously tried the wilcoxon signed-rank test using R, however an error appeared in that this cannot produce an accurate p-value due to presence of 0's?

Any advice or help would be appreciated :)

Also -- I have done a correlation test of these data (Pearson correlation r = 0.82, P < 0.001)